# SendGrid emailing API , send email attachment

Tags: java, sendgrid

Am using sendgrid to send emails and it works fine using the following code
but its without attachment.

```
package sendgrid;

import com.sendgrid.Content;
import com.sendgrid.Email;
import com.sendgrid.Mail;
import com.sendgrid.Method;
import com.sendgrid.Request;
import com.sendgrid.Response;
import com.sendgrid.SendGrid;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SendEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Email from = new Email("test@example.com");
    String subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid Java Library!";

    Email to = new Email("shareef@gmail.com");
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("SG.rIEh84OgQBybYEJcOMie1wd.AZqqdWNYXbOqTarUJcG-iSg0UtHJtCto4oe6tVzn6es");
    Request request = new Request();
    try {

      request.method = Method.POST;
      request.endpoint = "mail/send";
      request.body = mail.build();

      Response response = sg.api(request);
      System.out.println(response.statusCode);
      System.out.println(response.body);
      System.out.println(response.headers);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }

}
```

But what i need is to send attachments with it so i searched github source and the web documentation API , and for some reason there is no javadocs but there was an example [GitHub sendgrid](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/search?q=Attachments&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) so am trying until it works , i narrowed down some exceptions and response code , at first i was getting unauthorized the forbidden and it got better to response 202 , means valid and queued ([check here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html)) any way here is my code that dose send an email and with attachments but when you open the attachment its zero size and says cannot open or preview the file !

```
 package sendgrid;

    import com.sendgrid.Attachments;
    import com.sendgrid.Content;
    import com.sendgrid.Email;
    import com.sendgrid.Mail;
    import com.sendgrid.MailSettings;
    import com.sendgrid.Method;
    import com.sendgrid.Request;
    import com.sendgrid.SendGrid;
    import com.sendgrid.Setting;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;


    public class SendEmailAttachmentV2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            sendmail();
        }

        // Fully populated Mail object
        public static void sendmail() throws IOException {

            com.sendgrid.Response response1;

            Email from = new Email("shareef@gmail.com");
            String subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid Java Library!";

            Email to = new Email("shareef@gmail.com");
            Content content = new Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
            Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

            File file = new File("C:\\x.png");
            byte[] fileData = null;
            try {
                fileData = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }

            Attachments attachments3 = new Attachments();            
            attachments3.setContent(new String(fileData, 0, (int) file.length(), "UTF-8"));
            attachments3.setType("image/png");//"application/pdf"
            attachments3.setFilename("x.png");
            attachments3.setDisposition("attachment");
            attachments3.setContentId("Banner");
            mail.addAttachments(attachments3);


            MailSettings mailSettings = new MailSettings();
            Setting sandBoxMode = new Setting();
            sandBoxMode.setEnable(true);
            mailSettings.setSandboxMode(sandBoxMode);

            SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("SG.1Hg78VK0TJ6kexUnByZUYg.LAa5A4GufssZ9lpPQdV6PcZCY6SZ9Xq6LvqfMRG0wesKw");
            Request request1 = new Request();
            try {
                request1.method = Method.POST;
                request1.endpoint = "mail/send";

                request1.body = mail.build();

                response1 = sg.api(request1);
                System.out.println(response1.statusCode);
                System.out.println(response1.body);
                System.out.println(response1.headers);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

**FYI**: use your generated API key that generated from the console of sendgrid

Comment: You should remove the key from your code example

Comment: yes thanks @IcedDante i have put random one not real one i will re random it any way

Comment: hi, @shareef can you tell me how many emails that I can send in one go, is there any limit on java sdk for sendgrid?

Comment: Hi @OnkarMusale, you can check their site for updated info docs, or just do live chat they are very responsive!

Comment: @shareef Thank you so much for your response, I just found out that we can send 10k to 15k per second, but recommended is 1k per second.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When i executed the code i got the following message in logs in netbeans

```
 202
 
 {X-Frame-Options=DENY, Server=nginx, Connection=keep-alive,
 X-Message-Id=vqVw2RtUShSVQ_ymVEVqaw, Content-Length=0, Date=Tue, 26
 Jul 2016 20:05:54 GMT, Content-Type=text/plain; charset=utf-8}
```

The trick to solve the issue is to encode the attachment using commons apache codec [commons-codec-1.8.jar](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi) and its `encodeAsString` method from package

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

```
Attachments attachments3 = new Attachments();
Base64 x = new Base64();
String imageDataString = x.encodeAsString(fileData);
attachments3.setContent(imageDataString);
attachments3.setType("image/png");//"application/pdf"
attachments3.setFilename("x.png");
attachments3.setDisposition("attachment");
attachments3.setContentId("Banner");
mail.addAttachments(attachments3);
```

Even the content-length was retruned as 0 in response **it worked**.

Comment: Thanks , But the attachment sent with the email is complete new sheet. In my case , I want to sent the excel which contains data as a result of execution.  Kindly let me know how to sent the file excel file as attachment from local system

Answer (score 6):

This is the way you can send attachments using SendGrid API.

```
Mail mail = createEmail();
    Attachments attachments = new Attachments();
    Base64 x = new Base64();
    String encodedString = x.encodeAsString(loadPdfFromClasspath());
    attachments.setContent(encodedString);
    attachments.setDisposition("attachment");
    attachments.setFilename("xyx.pdf");
    attachments.setType("application/pdf");
    mail.addAttachments(attachments);


try {
        request.method = com.sendgrid.Method.POST;
        request.endpoint = "mail/send";
        request.body = mail.build();
        // Uncomment once connectivity with sendgrid is resolved
        Response response = sg.api(request);

}catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me ([the latest maven version SendGrid Java » 4.4.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sendgrid/sendgrid-java/4.4.1)):

```
        import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Attachments;
        import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Content;
        import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Email;
        import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.Mail;

        ......

        Content content = new Content("text/html", body);
        Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
        Path file = Paths.get(filePath);
        Attachments attachments = new Attachments();
        attachments.setFilename(file.getFileName().toString());
        attachments.setType("application/pdf");
        attachments.setDisposition("attachment");

        byte[] attachmentContentBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
        String attachmentContent = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(attachmentContentBytes);
        attachments.setContent(attachmentContent);
        mail.addAttachments(attachments);

        SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(apiKey);
        Request request = new Request();

        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());
        Response response = sg.api(request);
```

Comment: I guess it should be 

    `String attachmentContent = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(attachmentContentBytes);`

instead of 
    `String attachmentContent = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(attachmentContentBytes);`

Comment: @CodeTripper, sure. From [baeldung.com:](https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode) _"The MIME encoder generates a Base64-encoded output using the basic alphabet but in a MIME-friendly format. Each line of the output is no longer than 76 characters and ends with a carriage return followed by a linefeed (\r\n)"_